# VEVO.com video thumbnail

Tags: html, api, iframe, video

How do I access the url for a vevo video thumbnail? youtube makes it easy by hosting predicatably located images, and vimeo requires that you go through their api. But what about vevo? For example, give the following embed code:

How do I access a corresponding thumbnail?